# Grouping by Unique ID for JSON Array

Tags: java

> Blockquote

I have below JSON Input Request which has to be group by **ID** parameter.

**Input :**

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1234",
        "CustomerName": "KUMAR",
        "BranchName": "HARBOUR",
        "SchemeName": "GOLD",
        "MobileNumber": "123456789",
        "CustomerType": "PRIMARY",
        "DedupeFound" : "NO"
        
    },
    {
        "ID": "1234",
        "CustomerName": "SEAN",
        "BranchName": "HARBOUR",
        "SchemeName": "GOLD",
        "MobileNumber": "123456789",
        "CustomerType": "SECONDARY",
        "DedupeFound" : "YES"
    },
    {
        "ID": "5678",
        "CustomerName": "MARK",
        "BranchName": "CANTONMENT",
        "SchemeName": "DIAMOND",
        "MobileNumber": "123456789",
        "CustomerType": "PRIMARY",
        "DedupeFound" : "NO"
    },
    {
        "ID": "5678",
        "CustomerName": "STEVE",
        "BranchName": "CANTONMENT",
        "SchemeName": "DIAMOND",
        "MobileNumber": "123456789",
        "CustomerType": "SECONDARY",
        "DedupeFound" : "YES"
    }
]
```

The above request needs to be transformed in the below way

1. First records to be grouped based on ID Tag and only primary ID's details needs to be displayed
2. Inside the ID Record details . I have an DedupeDetails Array for both the customers.

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1234",
        "CustomerName": "KUMAR",           // Only Primary Customer Details for the 
        "BranchName": "HARBOUR",           //  ID Tag to be displayed here
        "SchemeName": "GOLD",
        "MobileNumber": "123456789"
        "DedupeDetails": [
            {
                "CustomerType": "PRIMARY"
                "CustomerName": "KUMAR",
                "DedupeFound" : "NO"
            },
            {
                "CustomerType": "SECONDARY"
                "CustomerName": "SEAN",
                "DedupeFound" : "YES"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "5678",
        "CustomerName": "MARK",
        "BranchName": "CANTONMENT",
        "SchemeName": "DIAMOND",
        "MobileNumber": "123456789"
        "DedupeDetails": [
            {
                "CustomerType": "PRIMARY"
                "CustomerName": "MARK",
                "DedupeFound" : "NO"
            },
            {
                "CustomerType": "SECONDARY"
                "CustomerName": "STEVE",
                "DedupeFound" : "YES"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have started with the java code in apache camel . where I am able to map json string to Object List successfully. I am still clueless on how to do grouping to achieve the output.

Note : I am a newbie to java . Any Suggestions / Corrections are highly recommended.

**Java**

```
package com.mycompany.Login;

import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Time;
import com.mycompany.Login.*;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mycompany.Dedupe.DedupeRoot.DedupeRes;




public class LoginMapping implements Processor{
    public void process(Exchange ex)throws Exception{ 
    
        try {   
        
           
            String responseString = {Input mentioned in post};          
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);         
            List<DedupeRes> dedupe = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(responseString, DedupeRes[].class));  
            int total = dedupe.size();          
            if (total > 0)
            {               
                for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {                   
                    
                }               
            }
    
     ex.getIn().setBody(responseString);
        }       
        catch(Exception e) {
            ex.getIn().setHeader("ExpMsg", "Undefined");
            throw e;
        }   
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must create `DedupeDetail` class:

```java
public class DedupeDetail {

    String CustomerType;
    String CustomerName;
    String DedupeFound;

    public DedupeDetail(String customerType, String customerName, String dedupeFound) {
        CustomerType = customerType;
        CustomerName = customerName;
        DedupeFound = dedupeFound;
    }
}
```

Then create `DedupeResultFinal` with converter:

```java
public class DedupeResultFinal {

    String ID;
    String CustomerName;
    String BranchName;
    String SchemeName;
    String MobileNumber;
    List<DedupeDetail> DedupeDetails;

    public DedupeResultFinal() {
    }

    public DedupeResultFinal(List<DedupeDetail> dedupeDetails) {
        DedupeDetails = dedupeDetails;
    }// ... other constructor and getter and setter

    public static DedupeResultFinal convertToFinal(HashMap<String, String> dedupeRes){
        DedupeResultFinal dedupeResultFinal = new DedupeResultFinal();

        dedupeResultFinal.setBranchName(dedupeRes.get("BranchName"));
        dedupeResultFinal.setCustomerName(dedupeRes.get("CustomerName"));
        dedupeResultFinal.setID(dedupeRes.get("ID"));
        dedupeResultFinal.setMobileNumber(dedupeRes.get("MobileNumber"));
        dedupeResultFinal.setSchemeName(dedupeRes.get("SchemeName"));

        return dedupeResultFinal;

    }
}
```

And then your method must be like this:

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String responseString = {Input mentioned in post};
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            List<HashMap<String, String>> dedupe = mapper.readValue(responseString, new ArrayList<String>().getClass());
            Map<String, DedupeResultFinal> map = new HashMap<>();

            for (HashMap<String, String> dedupeRes : dedupe) {
                if (map.get(dedupeRes.get("ID")) != null){
                    DedupeDetail dedupeDetail = new DedupeDetail(dedupeRes.get("CustomerType"), dedupeRes.get("CustomerName"), dedupeRes.get("DedupeFound"));
                    map.get(dedupeRes.get("ID")).getDedupeDetails().add(dedupeDetail);
                }else {
                    DedupeDetail dedupeDetail =  new DedupeDetail(dedupeRes.get("CustomerType"), dedupeRes.get("CustomerName"), dedupeRes.get("DedupeFound"));
                    DedupeResultFinal dedupeResultFinal = DedupeResultFinal.convertToFinal(dedupeRes);
                    List<DedupeDetail> dedupeDetails = new ArrayList<>();
                    dedupeDetails.add(dedupeDetail);
                    dedupeResultFinal.setDedupeDetails(dedupeDetails);

                    map.put(dedupeRes.get("ID"), dedupeResultFinal);
                }
            }

           List<DedupeResultFinal> finalDedup = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(finalDedup);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks hani for the solution. But I am facing this error when trying to build jar.   incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.Veritas.Test.DedupeResultFinal>

Comment: Well you take List the upper class first and then cast to the lower class .So when you get the list, your list is List<Object> and after iterate ،you have to cast each member  to DedupeResultFinal.

Answer (score 1):

Complete code implementation, try it.

```
public class T {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    static {
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    public static <T> List<T> parseObjectList(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(
                    json,
                    TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(ArrayList.class, clazz)
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static <T> String toJsonString(T t) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String responseString = "[{\"ID\":\"1234\",\"CustomerName\":\"KUMAR\",\"BranchName\":\"HARBOUR\",\"SchemeName\":\"GOLD\",\"MobileNumber\":\"123456789\",\"CustomerType\":\"PRIMARY\",\"DedupeFound\":\"NO\"},{\"ID\":\"1234\",\"CustomerName\":\"SEAN\",\"BranchName\":\"HARBOUR\",\"SchemeName\":\"GOLD\",\"MobileNumber\":\"123456789\",\"CustomerType\":\"SECONDARY\",\"DedupeFound\":\"YES\"},{\"ID\":\"5678\",\"CustomerName\":\"MARK\",\"BranchName\":\"CANTONMENT\",\"SchemeName\":\"DIAMOND\",\"MobileNumber\":\"123456789\",\"CustomerType\":\"PRIMARY\",\"DedupeFound\":\"NO\"},{\"ID\":\"5678\",\"CustomerName\":\"STEVE\",\"BranchName\":\"CANTONMENT\",\"SchemeName\":\"DIAMOND\",\"MobileNumber\":\"123456789\",\"CustomerType\":\"SECONDARY\",\"DedupeFound\":\"YES\"}]";
            List<DedupeRes> list = parseObjectList(responseString, DedupeRes.class);
            if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                Map<String, List<DedupeRes>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DedupeRes::getID));
                List<Res> resList = new ArrayList<>();
                map.forEach((k, v) -> resList.add(listToRes(v)));
                responseString = toJsonString(resList);
                System.out.println(responseString);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // xx
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Res listToRes(List<DedupeRes> list) {
        Res res = new Res();
        res.setDedupeDetails(new ArrayList<>());
        for (DedupeRes dedupeRes : list) {
            if (Objects.equals("PRIMARY", dedupeRes.getCustomerType())) {
                // if you used spring -> BeanUtils.copyProperties(dedupeRes, res);
                res.setID(dedupeRes.getID());
                res.setBranchName(dedupeRes.getBranchName());
                res.setCustomerName(dedupeRes.getCustomerName());
                res.setMobileNumber(dedupeRes.getMobileNumber());
                res.setSchemeName(dedupeRes.getSchemeName());
            }
            DedupeDetails details = new DedupeDetails();
            //
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(dedupeRes, details);
            res.getDedupeDetails().add(details);
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Data
    private static class DedupeRes {
        @JsonProperty("ID")
        private String ID;
        @JsonProperty("CustomerName")
        private String CustomerName;
        @JsonProperty("BranchName")
        private String BranchName;
        @JsonProperty("SchemeName")
        private String SchemeName;
        @JsonProperty("MobileNumber")
        private String MobileNumber;
        @JsonProperty("CustomerType")
        private String CustomerType;
        @JsonProperty("DedupeFound")
        private String DedupeFound;
    }

    @Data
    private static class Res {
        @JsonProperty("ID")
        private String ID;
        @JsonProperty("CustomerName")
        private String CustomerName;
        @JsonProperty("BranchName")
        private String BranchName;
        @JsonProperty("SchemeName")
        private String SchemeName;
        @JsonProperty("MobileNumber")
        private String MobileNumber;
        @JsonProperty("dedupeDetails")
        private List<DedupeDetails> dedupeDetails;
    }

    @Data
    private static class DedupeDetails {
        @JsonProperty("CustomerType")
        private String CustomerType;
        @JsonProperty("CustomerName")
        private String CustomerName;
        @JsonProperty("DedupeFound")
        private String DedupeFound;
    }
}
```

consule.

```
[{"ID":"1234","CustomerName":"KUMAR","BranchName":"HARBOUR","SchemeName":"GOLD","MobileNumber":"123456789","dedupeDetails":[{"CustomerType":"PRIMARY","CustomerName":"KUMAR","DedupeFound":"NO"},{"CustomerType":"SECONDARY","CustomerName":"SEAN","DedupeFound":"YES"}]},{"ID":"5678","CustomerName":"MARK","BranchName":"CANTONMENT","SchemeName":"DIAMOND","MobileNumber":"123456789","dedupeDetails":[{"CustomerType":"PRIMARY","CustomerName":"MARK","DedupeFound":"NO"},{"CustomerType":"SECONDARY","CustomerName":"STEVE","DedupeFound":"YES"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON library such as *Josson* to do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(yourJsonString);
```

**Method 1**

Find the primary record of each group from the root node.

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "group(ID, DedupeDetails:map(CustomerType, CustomerName, DedupeFound))@" +
    ".let($id:ID, $pri:$.[ID=$id & CustomerType='PRIMARY'])" +
    ".field($pri.CustomerName, $pri.BranchName, $pri.SchemeName, $pri.MobileNumber)");

System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Method 2**

Find the primary record within each group.

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "group(ID)@" +
    ".let($pri: elements[CustomerType='PRIMARY'])" +
    ".field($pri.CustomerName, $pri.BranchName, $pri.SchemeName, $pri.MobileNumber," +
    "       elements:, DedupeDetails:elements.map(CustomerType, CustomerName, DedupeFound))");

System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Method 3**

Use `mergeObjects()` instead of `let()` to do the task.

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "group(ID)@" +
    ".mergeObjects(" +
    "  elements[CustomerType='PRIMARY'].map(ID, CustomerName, BranchName, SchemeName, MobileNumber)," +
    "  map(DedupeDetails:elements.map(CustomerType, CustomerName, DedupeFound))" +
    ")");

System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```